# periodic functions tending to zero

Tags: solution-verification, problem-solving, periodic-functions

This is Problem 3.4.13 from $\textbf{ Problems in Real Analysis Advanced Calculus on the Real Axis.}$

> Let $f_1, f_2,\ldots,f_n:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R} $ be periodic functions such that
> \[
> \lim_{x\to\infty} \left(f_1(x)+f_2(x)+\cdots f_n(x)\right) = 0
> \]
> Prove that $f_1=f_2=\cdots=f_n$

However, is it alright to reason as follows?

> If $n\leq 2$, then it is obvious. If $n\geq 3$ choose two elements from a Hamel basis $\mathcal{H}$, say $a, b$.
> Write $x = \sum_{y\in \mathcal{H}} (x,y)\, y$ then
> \[
> f_1(x) = (x,a)a-(x,b)b 
> \]
> \[
> f_2(x) = \sum_{y\neq a} (x,y)\,y 
> \]
> \[
> f_3(x) = -\sum_{y\neq b} (x,y)\,y 
> \]
> and $f_i(x) = 0$ for all $i\geq 4$

And I am currently at a loss if the problem is wrong.
It seems to me that not only the functions are different but they don't share a period.

## Edit

A Hamel basis is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What about the case $n=2$ and $f_2=-f_1$?

Comment: Yes I was careless when I wrote “obvious”

Comment: A "Hamel basis"? And from your writing $x$ as the sum of $(x,y)y$, apparently you mean an orthonormal basis, though you failed to mention this. But from the problem statement the space where $x$ is found is $\Bbb R$. There are only two orthonormal bases for $\Bbb R$, those being $\{1\}$ and $\{-1\}$. These do not have any "two elements $a,b$" if they are distinct. And even if you were in some space where this made sense, why would $f_1(x) = (x,a)a-(x,b)b$? much less your later statements,

Comment: @kazuki Expanding on the first comment, what about $f_n = -f_1 -f_2 -\dots -f_{n-1}$ with arbitrary periodic functions $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_{n-1}$ that have commensurable periods.

Comment: @dxiv I thought the problem was wrong and tried to generalize it to that not only the functions can be different but also they possibly don't share a period.